# Как сделать переданные props состоянием компонента?

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть 2 компонента 
Первый PageExample - это контейнер который ходит в api за данными, пришедшие по апи данные пишутся в state.

Второй MyModal - обычный компонент в который через пропсы передаются данные из родительского this.state

Как в MyModal правильно присвоить переданные props в локальный state. 
То есть я хочу чтобы переданные пропсы стали состоянием MyModal.
Возможно ли это? Если да то в каком методе это правильнее делать, в конструкторе или в componentDidMount и т.п.? Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно все это сделать, как вы и хотите. Вот к примеру в родительском `PageExample` вы передаете посредством `props` данные, которые получили из API и записали в `dataAPI` стэйта, в `MyModal` компонент.

Предположим, что в `PageExample` есть такая функция, в которой получаем данные и кладем в стэйт:

```
loadDatafromAPI() {
  // тут какой-то код получения данных (к примеру)
  let data = ...

  // и запись этих данных в state
  this.setState({
     dataAPI: data
  });
}
```

А уже потом внутри `PageExample` вы создаете свой `MyModal` компонент, в который передаете эти данные посредством `props`:

```
<MyModal data={this.state.dataAPI} />
```

а уже внутри вашего `MyModal`, в конструкторе, можно их присвоить в локальный стэйт:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    dataAPI: props.data
  }
}
```

По поводу `componentDidMount` - можно и в нем, к примеру вот тут: [componentDidMount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) рекомендуют загружать данные с удаленной конечной точки (для сетевых запросов) именно внутри него. Однако вызов `setState({..})` в этом методе вызовет дополнительный рендеринг, но это произойдет до того, как браузер обновит экран.  Я бы писал в конструторе.

Comment: Конструктор вызовется только один раз при инициализации компонента. На момент вызова api ещё не успело отдать данные, state пустой. Может есть какой-то метод жизненного цикла в котором можно сделать this.setState({data: this.props.dataApi}) ?

Comment: @abakan ага, есть такая возможность через `componentWillReceiveProps` но он в новой версии реакта устарел... хотя, вот можно заюзать: `getDerivedStateFromProps`. Ссылка: [componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops)

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо

Comment: @abakan а еще можно юзать `props` родителя просто, в случае необходимости обновления данных - передавать через пропсы колбэк на обновление `props`. Ну это так, к слову о том, как сделать еще.

Comment: Сейчас так и сделано. У меня просто при изменении данных в модалке данные менялись и на странице, то есть в родителе. Вот хотел от этого избавиться)